# jQuery Page Performance with .Length

Tags: jquery, performance, fadein, fadeout

Having some performance issues with jQuery.

I'm iterating through all the posts made in my Wordpress theme, each post is designated a div dynamically: ie. container1. So, mostly for experimentation I'm making a slideshow that shows each post, then returns to the first after the it's reached the final div. To reset the slider I keep iterating until the loop sees a div that doesn't exist (using 'if (!$('#container'+i).length == 0)').

I'm sure this is fairly awful code, but as I said it's 90% experimentation, It's working, except performance is terrible (100% cpu usage by Chrome Renderer). I'll paste my code below, any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
// UI FUNCTIONS

var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

    i = 1;

    //iterates through all divs hiding them, calls delayedLoop() once all divs are hidden
    function resetdiv() {
        if (!$('#container'+i).length == 0) {
                $('#container'+i).stop().hide();
                i++;
                resetdiv();
               }

         else {
                i = 1;  
                setTimeout(function() { delayedLoop() },1000);     
              } 
    }

    //Hides current div, incretments i and calls delayedLoop after a delay
    function hidediv() {
        $('#container'+i).stop().fadeOut('slow');
        i++;
        setTimeout(function() { delayedLoop() },1000);      
        }

    //iterates through divs, showing current once and calling hidediv after a delay, after all divs have been iterated sets i = 0 and calls reset divs
    function delayedLoop(){
               if (!$('#container'+i).length == 0) {
                        $('#container'+i).stop().fadeIn('slow');
                        setTimeout(function() { hidediv() },10000);
                        //delayedLoop()
                     }

               else {

                    i = 1;  
                    setTimeout(function() { resetdiv(); },1000);
                    }


                }

$( document ).ready(function() {
        resetdiv();
});
```

Comment: Its look like infinite loop. You don't have console errors because you are using timeout. But for sure, its a bad practice.

Comment: Yeah fair point - any idea how I should fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var loopInterval, current = 0;
    var divs = $('div[id^="container"]');

    function resetdiv() {

        divs.stop().hide();
        current = 0;

        clearInterval(loopInterval);
        loopInterval = setInterval(function() {
            if (current > divs.length) {
                current = 0;
            }
            $(divs.get(current++)).stop().fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
        }, 4000);

    }

    resetdiv();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3M2Vg/3/)

Comment: fantastic! thanks heaps for you help. so much more elegant than my clumsy approach.